# EF Core randomly renames a column, despite no changes to model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In my ASP.Net Core MVC app, I have a simple `Game` class, plus 2 `GameRequest` and `GameResponse` classes (in snippets below) that are used for making requests, or for displaying on a view.

On adding a new migration (for an unrelated feature), I noticed EF Core adding a `.RenameColumn()` operation, specifically from `Games.NumberCodeDisplay -> Games.NumberCode`, which makes no sense. The `Games` table *never had the `NumberCodeDisplay` column in the first place, even in the previous migration where it was created.*

Curiously, this incorrect column name is the same as that of `GameResponse`'s despite it not being in the app's `DbContext`.

```
// GameModels.cs

public class Game
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string NameCode { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public decimal NumberCode { get; set; } // <--- this property has *never* changed
    public int YearReleased { get; set; }
}

public class GameRequest
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string NameCode { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public decimal NumberCode { get; set; }
    public int YearReleased { get; set; }
}

public class GameResponse
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string NameCode { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string NumberCodeDisplay { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public int YearReleased { get; set; }

    public static string GetNumberCodeDisplay(decimal numberCode)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

```
// migration file generated after `add-migration` 

public partial class AddField_Game_CoverImageUrl : Migration
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.RenameColumn(
            name: "NumberCodeDisplay",
            table: "Games",
            newName: "NumberCode");
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.RenameColumn(
            name: "NumberCode",
            table: "Games",
            newName: "NumberCodeDisplay");
    }
}
```

```
// AppDbContext.cs

public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Song> Songs { get; set; } = default!;
    public DbSet<Game> Games { get; set; } = default!;
}
```

Comment: Can you add the previous migration?

Comment: It just indicates the former name of the property is  NumberCodeDisplay and now you modify the name to NumberCode,have you attached any attribute or configured in your dbcontext OnModelCreating method?It hard to reproduce the issue with current codes you provided

Comment: @RuikaiFeng The DbContext doesn't have `OnModelCreating()` for now. The entity model is as I described in the post (`Game` class). 

Although, I forgot to add the previous migration and the model snapshot files, and after checking those I found that they use the wrong column name (despite the `Game` class still being correct). For now, I've just manually edited them and I can keep adding more migrations now.

Thanks though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found the problem, though I don't really know what caused it in the first place.**

I forgot to add the previous migration files where I created the table (let's call it `Migration_1`; the empty migration in the post would be `Migration_2`), and the model snapshot file. But what I've found is that:

- The C# model class is always correct (`Game` has a field called `NumberCode`, never has it been `NumberCodeDisplay`)
- I added the `Migration_1` migration. The resulting migration file `[timestamp]_Migration_1.cs` is correct:

```
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Games",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                    Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: false),
                    NameCode = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: false),
                    NumberCode = table.Column<decimal>(type: "decimal(18,2)", nullable: false),
                    YearReleased = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Games", x => x.Id);
                });
        }
```

- However, the *migration designer file* (`[timestamp]_Migration_1.Designer.cs`) for some reason incorrectly specified that a `Games` table with the `NumberCodeDisplay` column should be created (**before being applied to the actual database**):

```
    partial class Add_Game
    {
        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override void BuildTargetModel(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
#pragma warning disable 612, 618
            modelBuilder
                .HasAnnotation("ProductVersion", "7.0.7")
                .HasAnnotation("Relational:MaxIdentifierLength", 128);

            SqlServerModelBuilderExtensions.UseIdentityColumns(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity("MyProject.Models.Game", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<int>("Id")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                        .HasColumnType("int");

                    SqlServerPropertyBuilderExtensions.UseIdentityColumn(b.Property<int>("Id"));

                    b.Property<string>("Name")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                    b.Property<string>("NameCode")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                    b.Property<decimal>("NumberCodeDisplay") // <------ Here
                        .HasColumnType("decimal(18,2)");

                    b.Property<int>("YearReleased")
                        .HasColumnType("int");

                    b.HasKey("Id");

                    b.ToTable("Games");
                });
            // ...
        }
    }
```

- But in the database itself, the `Games` table *does* have the correct `NumberCode` column name.
  [image]

**This is probably due to me adding/removing some migrations after `Migration_1`**, notably there were a couple "`Migration_2`s" before I decided to cut out all the model changes (for an unrelated feature) and test out an empty migration (the current `Migration_2`). But I can't be sure.

For now, I've just manually edited `Migration_1`'s designer file, and the model snapshot file, and then further migrations wouldn't have the rename again.